# Looking for the source of this map from Quantum Leap (2022)

Tags: quantum-leap-2022

In an episode from Season 1 of *[Quantum Leap (2022)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt17043230/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0_tt_8_nm_0_q_quantum%2520lea)*, there's a scene in which Janis and Magic are chatting in front of some sort of screen displaying a map of the world with various links between cities:

[image]

I'm curious as to the source of this image.

Unfortunately I lost track of the specific episode this image was from, but I believe it was either "Paging Dr. Song" (E10) or "Leap. Die. Repeat." (E11).

I don't think there's an in-universe explanation for this image, nor how the city links are related to Project Quantum Leap (but am happy to accept one, if there is one).

Nevertheless, I would also like to know the out-of-universe source of the image and what (if anything) the links between the cities are supposed to represent.

Comment: Gotta be made up for the show.  There's nowhere in Libya that marked point, nor in Nunavut (Canada).  (Well, maybe not _nowhere_, it's obviously a place, but the closest points to the marks are exceedingly minor. "Baker Lake had a population of 2,061")

Comment: The U.K. location appears to be Manchester.  Spain is closer to Salmanca than Madrid.  France is Béziers or Narbonne, not even Montpellier or Marseille.  The central European spot is Dresden or Praha (Prague), not Berlin.  There appears to be a dot in Bir Lehlou, Western Sahara.  Basically this is not a map that would get made up in real life.

Comment: @DavidW actually such a map could be made in real life if it wasn't a map of airline routes between major cities, but a map of points which were of interest for some reason.  Possibly it was a made as a map of world wide equivalents of "Ley lines" and the points they lead to, in the Quantum Leap universe.

Comment: Let's not forget that the leaper in Quantum Leap goes through both time and space (though mostly seems confined to the USA). Even if the location appears to have nobody there today, that may not always have been the case, even if it's just one person to leap into.